# Missing service providers on composer update

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I ran `composer install --no-dev` before having to manually deploy to a client's server by FTP that lacks SSH access. When I did so, I received the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found in C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 158
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\artisan:0
PHP   2. require_once() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\artisan:30
PHP   3. require() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\bootstrap\start.php:60
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\start.php:210
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:58
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:122
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Way\\Generators\\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found","file":"C:\\Ampps\\www\\test.dev\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRe
pository.php","line":158}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found in C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 158
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\artisan:0
  PHP   2. require_once() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\artisan:30
  PHP   3. require() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\bootstrap\start.php:60
  PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\start.php:210
  PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:58
  PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider() C:\www\test.dev\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:122
```

Each of the `app.php` files has the line `'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'`.

This was working fine before running that composer command. Why did this happen and how can it be fixed?

Laravel 4.1.

Comment: do you have it in conposer.json on the root previous to make an composer -update?

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta Yes, in composer.json is the line `"require-dev": {"way/generators": "~2.6"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `composer.json` file, you have `way/generators` as a development machine dependency only. If you have the service provider `'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'` in each of the `app.php` file, then it would mean that `way/generators` is a development machine as well as the deployment machine dependency. By doing `composer install --no-dev`, you're saying that the packages that are development machine dependency only, shouldn't go in the `vendor` directory, which means that the package `way/generators` is not installed in the `vendor` directory. That's why you're getting the error.

Since `way/generators` is a development dependency only, you should remove `'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'` from `app/config.php`, so that the deployment machine wouldn't look for it.

Also if you're working on the development machine and performed `composer install --no-dev`, the `way/generators` package wouldn't be installed in the `vendor` directory and you'd get the above error. So you'd have to make the development machine environment as not `local` to test whether or not it'd work in the deployment machine.